# Efficiently compute 1xM Times MxM Times Mx1, N Times

Tags: performance, numpy

I need to compute a dot product for N rows; Let's say for each row I need to compute 1xM times MxM times Mx1. If I was looking at only one row, I'd have 1x1 from this calculation. I have N rows however, so I thought I would stack the rows, and feed it to the dot product; However I get NxN matrix as a result. The results I need are in the diagonal, but is there a faster way of doing this computation which also does not waste space? Ideally I'd like to end up with a Nx1 vector, not NxN matrix as a result.

Example

Single row

```
r = np.array([[1,2]]).T
R = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
```

gives

```
[[18]]
```

Multiple rows

```
rs = np.array([[1,2],[4,4]]).T
R = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
print np.dot(np.dot(rs.T,R), rs)

[[ 18  48]
 [ 48 128]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) alongwith the inner dot-product, like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,ji->i',np.dot(rs.T,R),rs)
```

Sample run -

```
In [215]: rs = np.random.rand(3,4)
     ...: R = np.random.rand(3,3)
     ...: out = np.dot(np.dot(rs.T,R), rs)
     ...: 

In [216]: np.diag(out)  # Diagonal elems is the expected o/p
Out[216]: array([ 1.11476081,  1.05112902,  0.32136029,  0.31318894])

In [217]: np.einsum('ij,ji->i',np.dot(rs.T,R),rs)
Out[217]: array([ 1.11476081,  1.05112902,  0.32136029,  0.31318894])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [233]: rs = np.random.rand(300,400)

In [234]: R = np.random.rand(300,300)

In [235]: %timeit np.diag(np.dot(np.dot(rs.T,R), rs))# Original soln
10 loops, best of 3: 84 ms per loop

In [236]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,kj,ki->j', rs, rs, R)# @DSM's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 65.2 ms per loop

In [237]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ji->i',np.dot(rs.T,R),rs)
10 loops, best of 3: 37.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: On my machine, my three-argument einsum is actually ten times slower than using your approach on large arrays.  (diag 7.4 ms, einsum+dot= 3.6, 3-einsum=73.2).  Too bad, I liked it.. :-/

Comment: @DSM Yeah I liked it too, to do everything inside `einsum` was a good job I thought! Undelete it maybe, people might like alternatives? :)

Comment: Using the `optimize=True` flag in `einsum` makes @DSM's solution comparable in time on my machine